# Prevent cacheing when using nginx reverse proxy cache

Tags: php, nginx, cache

is there a way to prevent cacheing for some pages when using nginx reverse proxy cache. like sending some king of header from php?

my version of nginx is 0.7.64

thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like...

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The [relevant section of RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) makes for interesting reading if you're wanting to control caching.